# How can I find the max length of a string in python protobufs?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, nanopb

I have a (proto2) .proto file with a definition akin to the following:

```
message foo {
  string myString = 1 [(nanopb).max_size = 20];
}
```

How can I find the max length of "myString" in python? To get the value of an enum, I can do something like myProto.myCoolEnum.Value(), but I haven't found anything analogous for getting max size for a string.

Comment: I think this might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836315/python-protocol-buffer-field-options

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Protocol Buffer field options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836315/python-protocol-buffer-field-options)